# im i using "this" the right way in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

This is my code

```
ImageCarousel = (function() {
var currentIndex, imageManager, imagesVO, jsonPath, values;

currentIndex = null;

jsonPath = "json/images.json";

imagesVO = [];

values = null;

imageManager = null;

function ImageCarousel() {
  this.loadJson();
}

ImageCarousel.prototype.loadJson = function() {
  var _this = this;
  return $.ajax(jsonPath, {
    success: function(data, status, xhr) {
      console.log("yea " + data);
      _this.currentIndex = 0;
      _this.imagesVO = data.images;
      _this.imageManager = new ImageManager(data.images);
      _this.imagesCount = _this.imagesVO.length;
      _this.switchToImage(_this.currentIndex);
      $('#next').click(function() {
        _this.currentIndex = _this.incrementIndexByOne(_this.currentIndex);
        return _this.switchToImage(_this.currentIndex);
      });
      return $('#prev').click(function() {
        _this.currentIndex = _this.decrementIndexByOne(_this.currentIndex);
        return _this.switchToImage(_this.currentIndex);
      });
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, err) {
      return $('#imageHolder').html("problem loading the json file, </br>make sure you are running this on your local server");
    },
    complete: function(xhr, status) {}
  });
};
```

am i right for using "this" to refer to vars inside ImageCarousel class? does it make those properties public? if so, how do I keep them private?

Comment: How do you want to be using `this`? There are several ways to use `this` and many of them bad. You can make private properties by not exposing them. If you add them to `this`, you've exposed them.

Comment: Didn't you mean to use `var` instead of `_this` there?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you're not using `this` correctly. Those properties you are trying to reference are all private, as in no outside code could really access them by invoking some property of `ImageCarousel`.

If you do want to make those variables public for whatever reason, do not declare them using `var`.  Instead, do something like `this.currentIndex = null` or `this.jsonPath = "json/images.json"`.  When you do that, you're essentially making those properties publicly accessible. Any outside code can access those properties simply by invoking `ImageCarousel.currentIndex`, `ImageCarousel.jsonPath`, etc. etc.

Comment: i dont understand. if i use function ImageCarousel() {
      imageHolderDiv = $('#imageHolder');
      loadJson();
//i get Uncaught ReferenceError: loadJson is not defined
    }

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things wrong with this. Here's the code w/ corrections:

```
var ImageCarousel = function () {
    var currentIndex, imageManager, imagesVO, jsonPath, values;

    currentIndex = null;

    jsonPath = "json/images.json";

    imagesVO = [];

    values = null;

    imageManager = null;

    var _this = this;

    this.loadJson = function () {
        return $.ajax(jsonPath, {
            success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                console.log("yea " + data);
                currentIndex = 0;
                imagesVO = data.images;
                imageManager = new ImageManager(data.images);
                imagesCount = imagesVO.length;
                switchToImage(currentIndex);
                $('#next').click(function () {
                    currentIndex = _this.incrementIndexByOne(currentIndex);
                    return _this.switchToImage(_this.currentIndex);
                });
                return $('#prev').click(function () {
                    currentIndex = _this.decrementIndexByOne(currentIndex);
                    return _this.switchToImage(currentIndex);
                });
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, err) {
                return $('#imageHolder').html("problem loading the json file, </br>make sure you are running this on your local server");
            },
            complete: function (xhr, status) {}
        });
    };
    this.loadJson();    
};

var someCarousel = new ImageCarousel(); // Example usage.
```

Effectively, `ImageCarousel` was declared twice. Once with `ImageCarousel = (function() {` and once with `function ImageCarousel()...`. I opted for the former.

If I understood you correctly, you wanted `currentIndex`, `imageManager`, `imagesVO`, `jsonPath`, and values to be private. For those, just do a var inside your function block, and they will be private to each instance of that `new`'d object. You can use them safely inside your `ImageCarousel` function with no worries (and no `_this`).

I left `_this` on the methods that you're calling inside of `loadJson` because (not being able to see their definitions here) I am assuming they are public methods. If they're private, just declare them inside your wrapper function and they will only be accessible within. If you want them to be public, use `this[functionName]` as I've done with loadJson.

So the affect of my code changes are:

- currentIndex, etc. are private.
- loadJson is public.

**EDIT**
A couple more things on using `prototype`. `prototype` is for "static" functions - meaning, that function doesn't exist for every instance of `ImageCarousel` objects. If you use it, you are to use it outside of the function's declaration. Otherwise, every time you `new` an `ImageCarousel` it will be re-defining `loadJson` unnecessarily. Here's a nice little demo app that shows what I mean a little more clearly: http://jsfiddle.net/d2BbA/